# Remember state of closed accordions on page load

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have multiple accordions on a single page. The default state is open. I am hoping to remember the state of all accordions when a person navigates back to that page.

I have tried to configure other examples of code but can not get someone else's case to work for mine. Can anyone help?

Jquery script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$( ".accordion" ).accordion({
collapsible: true,
activate: function(event, ui) {
$('h6', this).each(function() {
$(this).text($(this).text().replace('Close', 'Open'));
});
ui.newHeader.text(ui.newHeader.text().replace('Open', 'Close'));
}}).
find('h6').text(function(i, value) { return value + ' - Open'; }).
filter('*').text(function(i, value) { return value.replace('Open',       
'Close'); });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="accordion">
<h6 align="right"></h6>
<div>
    --Content Here--
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to set a cookie.  There have been, in the past, a number of cookie-related plugins for jQuery, or you can roll your own or use a different, 3rd-party solution.  I have used the Mozilla Foundation's "docCookies" to good effect.

Assuming you choose the latter, you must first have the script inside the HEAD element of your web page:

```
<script src="/path/to/docCookies.js"></script>
```

After this, you would need to add the call to your event handler(s) that open/close the accordions.

The prototype is this:

```
docCookies.setItem(name, value[, end[, path[, domain[, secure]]]])
```

So a simple call to this might be (using a made-up name and integer value for open/close):

```
docCookies.setItem("accordion1", 1); // accordion 1 is open
docCookies.setItem("accordion2", 0); // accordion 2 is closed
```

As I see it from your example above, you'd need to place this inside your "activate" function.

When your visitor first arrives, you'll have to have the server-side (PHP? or w/e... ) check for the presence of the "accordion1" (2,3, etc.) cookie(s) and, if they are set to '1', have it display the accordion as open when the page loads.